# Cannot push the unchanged files to GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, atlassian-sourcetree

**Objective:** Migrate a project from Stash to GitLab with every objects.

**Approach:** I know there is an approach to import the project directly in GitLab while creating a new project. But we do not have the import from Stash to GitLab button (may be some access issues).

The next approach taken is that:

- I cloned via SourceTree tool from Stash to my local disk.
- After that I ran the following commands in the project folder:
- `git remote set-url origin GITLAB-URL`
- `git init`
- `git add .`
- `git commit -m "message"`
- `git push -u origin master`

It didn't work out as if we run `git status`, it says:

```
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

I tried to push these project via Sourcetree. I can see all the project directories and files in the Unstaged files section. When I select few files and click on Stage Selected button, the files does not get moved to Staged files. I think for pushing the files into GitLab, I first need to stage the files but its not happening.

Comment: when you type `git remote -v` what is outputted?

Comment: If you do a git log are you commit listed?

Comment: @rLevv it displays the GITLAB URL

Comment: @SakuraKinomoto `git log` displays the commits that I have done till now in the Stash. I am trying to migrate the code base of the project from Stash to GITLAB. I have just cloned the project (using SourceTree) to my local system. I didnt make any code changes. Now I want to upload the code base (downloaded from Stash to my local system) to the GITLAB.